# Woocommerce adding to cart with post_id

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce, plugins

I'm dynamically making products with woocommerce and need to add them to the cart.  I have an ajax function that calls this in php plugin file:

```
         $name = $_POST['name'];
        $price = $_POST['price'];
        $post_id = wp_insert_post( array(
            'post_title' => 'new Product',
            'post_content' => 'here is product content',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post_type' => "product",
            'ID' => 1,
            ) );
            wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, 'simple', 'product_type' );
            update_post_meta( $post_id, '_visibility', 'visible' );
            update_post_meta( $post_id, '_stock_status', 'instock');
            update_post_meta( $post_id, 'total_sales', '0' );
            update_post_meta( $post_id, '_downloadable', 'no' );
            update_post_meta( $post_id, '_virtual', 'yes' );
            update_post_meta( $post_id, '_regular_price', $price );
            update_post_meta( $post_id, '_sale_price', '' );
            update_post_meta( $post_id, '_purchase_note', '' );
            update_post_meta( $post_id, '_featured', 'no' );
            update_post_meta( $post_id, '_weight', '' );
            update_post_meta( $post_id, '_length', '' );
            update_post_meta( $post_id, '_width', '' );
            update_post_meta( $post_id, '_height', '' );
            update_post_meta( $post_id, '_sku', '' );
            update_post_meta( $post_id, '_product_attributes', array() );
            update_post_meta( $post_id, '_sale_price_dates_from', '' );
            update_post_meta( $post_id, '_sale_price_dates_to', '' );
            update_post_meta( $post_id, '_price', '' );
            update_post_meta( $post_id, '_sold_individually', '' );
            update_post_meta( $post_id, '_manage_stock', 'no' );
            update_post_meta( $post_id, '_backorders', 'no' );
            update_post_meta( $post_id, 'product_id', '444' );
            update_post_meta( $post_id, '_stock', '' );
            WC()->cart->add_to_cart($post_id);
}
```

This creates a new product but doesn't add it to the cart.  Anyone have any idea why?

Comment: why are you specifying ID as static ?

Answer (score 0):

Below code will work!

```
$post_id = wp_insert_post( array(
            'post_title' => 'new Product',
            'post_content' => 'here is product content',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post_type' => "product"
           ) );
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($post_id);
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your time, I tried this and didn't work for me.  Do you happen to know if I need to initialize anything with woocommerce to use the WC() function so it actually pushed through to the cart?